# do numbers in an array contain sides of a valid triange

Tags: puzzle

Check if an array of `n` integers contains 3 numbers which can form a triangle (i.e. the sum of any of the two  numbers is bigger than the third).

Apparently, this can be done in `O(n)` time.

(the obvious `O(n log n)` solution is to sort the array so please don't)

Comment: Couldn't you loop through once, storing the two smallest and one largest integers. Then compare in O(n)?

Comment: Just to clarify, you're supposed only to check *if* the numbers exist, not to print the numbers?

Comment: @IAbstractDownvoteFactory 1, 2, 3, 10, 10, 10 smallest are not necessarily the solution

Comment: @MichałBentkowski I do not know.

Comment: I don't believe that it can be solved. For example, given the set 1,2,7,10,13,100,114 (not necessarily sorted, of course), how can one find detect the existence of a solution in a single pass? I would really be excited to see!

Comment: @LiorKogan +1 Great counterexample! My intuition is this problem is at least as hard as sorting. It has been discussed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5391207/how-to-know-that-a-triangle-triple-exists-in-our-array

Comment: @LiorKogan it doesn't have to be one pass.

Comment: @MK.: Correct. yet I don't believe that it can be solved in a constant number of passes.

Comment: @LiorKogan see below.   Basically a solution in O(nlog(M)) time where M is the range of input, hence constant.

Comment: Since M is input-dependent, it is not considered constant. It is called pseudo-linear time complexity. Nonetheless, nice solution.

Comment: @LiorKogan my reasoning is that max range has to be considered constant, otherwise we wouldn't be able to assume that even comparing 2 numbers is constant time.

Comment: @MK: Still, In general, O(nlog(M)) is not considered better than O(nlog(n). pseudo-linear algorithms may be better or worse, but should not be called linear/constant. See http://moodle.bracu.ac.bd/pluginfile.php/1906/mod_assignment/intro/ALGORITHMS%20LAB%2005.pdf for example (pseudo-linear time sorting algorithms)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's difficult to imagine N numbers (where N is moderately large) so that there is no triangle triplet. But we'll try:

Consider a growing sequence, where each next value is at the limit `N[i] = N[i-1] + N[i-2]`. It's nothing else than Fibonacci sequence. Approximately, it can be seen as a geometric progression with the factor of golden ratio (GRf ~= 1.618).
It can be seen that if the `N_largest < N_smallest * (GRf**(N-1))` then there sure will be a triangle triplet. This definition is quite fuzzy because of floating point versus integer and because of GRf, that is a limit and not an actual geometric factor. Anyway, carefully implemented it will give an O(n) test that can check if the there is sure a triplet. If not, then we have to perform some other tests (still thinking).

**EDIT**: A direct conclusion from fibonacci idea is that for integer input (as specified in Q) there will exist a garanteed solution for **any** possible input if the size of array will be larger than `log_GRf(MAX_INT)`, and this is 47 for 32 bits or 93 for 64 bits. Actually, we can use the largest value from the input array to define it better.

This gives us a following algorithm:

Step 1) Find MAX_VAL from input data :`O(n)`

Step 2) Compute the minimum array size that would guarantee the existence of the solution:
`N_LIMIT = log_base_GRf(MAX_VAL)` : `O(1)`

Step 3.1) if N > N_LIMIT : return `true` : `O(1)`

Step 3.2) else sort and use direct method `O(n*log(n))`

Because for large values of N (and it's the only case when the complexity matters) it is `O(n)` (or even `O(1)` in cases when `N > log_base_GRf(MAX_INT)`), we can say it's `O(n)`.

Comment: The fibonacci thought is definitely interesting but I don't think I you have a real solution here...

Comment: I'm not excited about having to say that O(n*log(n)) for small n is ok because it relies on the fact that we are only dealing with integers (64bit floats can get big), but I think this is pretty much the best you can do.