# Determinate the existence of a triangle given a sorted list

Tags: algorithm, computational-geometry

I have come across a problem about the determination of triangle, it says:

> Given a sorted integer array(length n), determinate whether you could
>   build a    triangle by choosing three integers from the array, the
>   answer is "yes" or "no".

A naive solution is by scanning all the possibilities but it turn out to be O(n^3), seems
 it will be C(n, 3) possibilities.

Comment: Also a duplicate of [How to know that a triangle triple exists in our array?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5391207/1328439)

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that the integers represent side lengths and array(0) > 0,

```cs
bool IsTriangle(int[] aray, int start) {
  if(array.length - start <= 2) return false;

  return  (array(start+2) < array(start+1) + array(start+0)) 
      || IsTriangle(array,start+1);
}
```

This works because the list of integers is sorted; thus the RHS will always be larger using any subsequent elements of the array, and the LHS will be smaller using any previous elements of the array, and thus can satisfy the triangle inequality only if the selected three consecutive elements satisfy it. This is of course O(n) and can easily be converted to a (less elegant but more performant) iterative solution.

Comment: I didn't understand what is meant by a triangle; could you illustrate what you assumed? I can't really comprehend this right now.

Comment: A triangle (defined by its side lengths) is any triple of side lengths such that the longest is strictly shorter than the sum of the two shorter. That is to say, c < a + b where c > a and c > b.

Comment: Ah I see, of course; I was thinking in terms of graphs

Comment: Don't we also need to test the following?